# ARC weak references in hash table

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, hashtable

I've using an NSHashTable to store weak references to objects. When an object in the hash table is deallocated and the reference is zeroed within the hash table, the pointer to nil still resides in the hash table, correct? So over time, if objects that are deallocated aren't directly removed from the hash table, the hash table will continue to grow in size? Right now, there is no easy way to send a notification to the object controlling the hash table that one of the hash tables elements have been removed (it's a game where feedback calls mean communication between objects is very indirect, and preferably stays that way). Should I iterate over the hash table periodically to remove nil references?

Comment: I don't think the table should grow in size when the objects are deallocated. No null pointer will stay in the table, but they would be removed instead. _These are just my thoughts about how it should work, didn't try it myself._

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question was posted several months ago, but for the record, NSHashTable **does** remove released weak references. So to answer the actual question, no, you don't need to iterate over the hash table periodically.

Comment: Note: NSHashTable.count does not get updated when weak references die off.  If you want to detect an empty NSHashTable, use (NSHashTable.anyObject == nil).

Comment: @mrgrieves But that is all right. Hash tables works that way. They will grow in size, but they will use those nil values for new values that are inserted to them.

Comment: @mrgrieves Thanks! You've just saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

I would make a manager class which is responsible for adding and removing objects you are speaking of. Thus I would notify the hash table in one of several ways:

- directly via method invocation (when hash table is referenced by manager)
- indirectly making hash table a manager's delegate object
- indirectly registering hashtable to observe any add/remove operations in manager
- indirectly by making manager sending a notification to notification center, which notification is listened by the hash table

It all depends how did you bind together those objects and which models suits the most actual design.

Comment: Great, thank you. Those are good ideas; I'll think about how they'd fit with what I've got.